# Add a bookmark in reStructuredText (rst)

Tags: hyperlink, bookmarks, restructuredtext

Is there reStructuredText syntax for the equivalent of:

```
Click <a href="#foo">here</a> to skip to the best section

... 

<a name="foo">This is the best section</a>
```

This has been answered in markdown, but does this exist in reStructuredText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an 'Internal Hyperlink Target' and can be done like this:

```
Click here_. to skip to the best section

.. _here:

This is the best section
```